# WCF error with hosting of a SL4 Navigation application

Tags: silverlight, wcf, iis-7, asp.net-membership

I have a SL navigation application, that currently runs on a shared hosting package with a 3rd party ISP. I can login, and register using the ASP.NET membership and role providers.

I have now setup a dedicated server, on which only my app will run. It does not yet have a domain name that points to it... I access it via an IP address.

I've copied the entire site (including the ClientBin and all the XAP's) to the new server, but the Authentication and Registration services don't work... they just return NotFound.

When I check Fiddler on the working site, this service is called :

```
www.myaddress.com/ClientBin/MyApp-Web-AuthenticationService.svc/binary/Login
```

which of course succeeds. However, on the other site, the fiddler trace looks the same (because I just copied the site) :

```
123.123.123.123/ClientBin/MyApp-Web-AuthenticationService.svc/binary/Login
```

but, the call fails with NotFound. Fiddler reports it as HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error. When I open

```
http://localhost/ClientBin/MyApp-Web-AuthenticationService.svc/binary/Login
```

on the server, I get the HTTP/1.1 500, as well as this description :

```
Handler "svc-Integrated" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list
```

Which leads me to believe that there is something wrong with my IIS config, as the exact same code is working on another system.

What is a "bad module"? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Normally this type of error is that ASP.Net is not activated or that a handler for svc is not registered or registered correctly.

In your case is looks a bit different. It could be that you have .net framework 4.0 code that you are trying to run in a .net framework 2.0 application pool.

Comment: The app runs in the DefaultAppPool, which I changed to .NET 4.0. I also tried making another app pool, and setting it to .NET 4.0. Same error.

Comment: Almost had it though... Needed to run asp_regiis.exe /i from %WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v4.

Answer (score 0):

IIS 500 errors often show up with more information in the Windows Event log - if you can somehow get access to that?

Also I've noticed that often the server will actually send debugging output back to the client that everything seems to ignore. Have you checked the entire raw response that is coming back from the server to see if there are any clues there?